# I lose my varible after method excution with nameerror

Tags: python-3.x

I just started learning python and now I have this error that may need some help to get over. I keep getting this NameError: name 'inp' is not defined  after code excution and my conclusion is that the variable only works inside the method and then gets lost in the end. if this is the case can you help me maintain the variable and if not can you tell me what's wrong with it

```
 def inpval():
    while True :
        try:
            inp = input('Choose Regimen >>>  ')
            inp = int(inp)
            if inp > 3 :
                print('Please Choose A Valid Regimen')
                continue

            else :
                break
        except:
                print('Kindly Type Numbers Only')
                continue
inpval()
print(inp)
```

Comment: You are losing it regardless of any exceptions. `inp` is a local variable, and so goes out of scope as soon as `inpval` exits. Either `return inp` (preferred) or add `global inp` to the beginning of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please return inp value,

```
def inpval():
    inp = int(input('Choose Regimen >>>  '))
    # Your conditions
    return inp

#function call in main function
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

That's because your function has not any return. You should put a return inp at the end of the function definition so you can access it when you call the function like:

```
def inpval():
    ...
    ...
    ...
    return inp
value = inpval()
```